# Что лучше: Include или function()?

Tags: include, php

Давно уже создаю свои проекты на пхп, открываю для себя что-то новое, что-то новое откладываю на позднее время, когда стану "мудрее". Постоянно различные функции хранил в отдельных файлах. Регистрация в одном месте, добавления комментариев в другом. Никогда не использовал `function()`. Сейчас вот решил пользоваться и этим. Возник вопрос.

Что лучше: если я создам один файл (более 1000 строк) и там будут все функции сайта, то есть он будет всегда искать нужную фукнцию там, при выполнения действий, или всё-таки лучше разделить всё это на группы и юзать `include`?

Просто раньше писал скрипты для одной онлайн игры, так там (на Сях), был один большой  файл с модом (более 10к строк). Вот подумал такое же сделать в пхп.

Что посоветуете?

(Добавлено):
Я хотел сделать таким образом. 
Есть один файл, где содержится множество `fucntion()`, есть обычные функции, например, регистрация. Сначала выполняется `register.php`, потом в регистре инклудится файл `allfunctions.php` (тот самый большой файл). 
Нормально ли так? И плохо ли это, когда в файле много инклудов? 
Что быстрее: инклуды нужных функций в разных файлах, или один файл с кучей функций?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы не советовал делать один большой файл. Помнится в одном из своих первых проектах, я сделал такую штучку, через год понадобилось внести корректировки и при том, что я комментировал, поиск нужного с многочисленными прокрутками документа вверх-вниз, отбил у меня охоту делать подобное навсегда. Наверное мой нынешний способ хранения функций/классов далёк от идеального, но меня, в общем и целом, устраивает: функции у меня разбиты на логические категории и каждая из таких групп, помещена в отдельный файл. Существует еще один файл, который инклюдится непосредственно в документ проекта, а уже в него я подключаю те документы с функциями, которые в данном проекте нужны. Получается что-то вроде модульной системы, если можно так назвать.

Comment: Про прокрутки огромного документа - Вы правы. Сталкивался с таким.
Тем не менее, иногда меня напрягает большое количество файлов.
Новый мелкий проект уже набрал 9 файлов, а это только начало.
Какую замену можете еще посоветовать? 
Еще прочитайте мой первый пост, я там обновил.
Спасибо

Comment: >  Что быстрее: инклуды нужных функций в разных файлах, или один файл с кучей функций?

Если говорить о скорости, то быстрее работает один большой файл, чем несколько маленьких:
один файл легче кэшировать, чем 10, один файл с HDD грузиться быстрее, чем 10 (*из основ физической записи на HDD*). Поэтому, если приоритет скорость, то конечно один большой, но повторюсь -  ужас как не удобно редактировать ))

Answer (score 10):

Касательно PHP, предлагаю как вариант использовать класс со статическими методами в качестве функций, и документируем согласно: [Документирование методов и функций](http://content-management-systems.info/node/110#dokumentirovanie_funktsii_i_metodov).

**Плюсы:**

1. Получаем экстаз от использования ООП.
2. Выигрыш в скорости за счет того что грузим всего один файл.
3. Любой более менее адекватный редактор обладает обзором дерева классов, что позволяет без труда, двойным кликом, перейти к определению метода.
4. Благодаря документированию, кайфуем при использовании intellisense
5. Получаем выигрыш в навигации, при условии что функции тематически распределены по классам (например класс Img - содержит функции по работе с картинками и т.д.)

Comment: > Получаем экстаз от использования ООП

+1

Comment: @Palmervan, пропаганда перверсий?

Comment: Вот от ООП я не получаю экстаз, может потому что я не умею нормально пользоваться..)
Если есть возможность, можете скинуть тексты, где легко описано ООП в php. Как оно делается и с чем потом его есть?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: [Как вариант](http://www.php.su/learnphp/phpoo/).

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос из серии что лучше и ответ как всегда - лучше баланс. Объединяйте тематические функции в одни файлы, лучше в классы. Соответственно по мере необходимости подгружайте.

Возможно есть инструменты, способный собрать проект для релиза, т.е. из кучи хорошо отредактированных файлов сделать один большой, в котором все будет нечитабельно, но работать будет быстрее. Это именно для заливки на сервер, а разработку думаю надо вести так, чтобы было удобно.

Answer (score 1):

В PHP 5+ появился ООП [Объектно ориентированное программирование](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) он идеально отвечает на все ваши вопросы. 
Очень советую [изучить](http://www.softtime.ru/info/articlephp.php?id_article=108), и по началу использовать везде где только возможно. А дальше опыт подскажет

И да, файлы более 1500 строк зло, никогда так не делайте если не хотите чтобы те кому придется ковырять ваш код вспоминали вас недобрым словом )))

Comment: я про строки сказал много, чтобы было более понятно. И этот код только я буду ковырять(пока не умру конечно) :D